# How can I see Google spreadsheets in Myanmar font?

Tags: google-sheets, font

I want to know whether it is possible to see Google spreadsheet in Myanmar font. Because in my Ubuntu operating system I am not able to see the  spreadsheet text in Myanmar font which show only boxes.

1. I had installed the Myanmar Zawgyi fonts from the following link.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/zawgyi-keyboard/downloads

2. I had tried Myanmar font tool chrome Extension.

I tried the above two points. Still am seeing only boxes.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had installed Myanmar Zawgyi font in my Ubuntu operating System and restarted solved the issue. Now i can clearly see the Myanmar text in google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Google Spreadsheets and the other Google Docs editors doesn't allow to upload fonts. Try choosing one of the available fonts offered by Google. For further details on how to change the font, see [Change the font in your file](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/189190?hl=en)